# How to join 3 tables in which 2 of them are connected to the other 1 but not to eachother

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 **tables**: `people`, `country`, `activity`

```
**country**
id | people_id
1     3
2     1
3     2
**activity**
id | people_id
1     2
2     3
3     1
**people**
id | name
1    david
2    daniel
3    mark
```

As you can see from above, `country` and `activity` are connected to **people** using `people_id` but `country` and `activity` have not connected to each other.

My question is: how to join these 3 tables?

Thank you for your time

Comment: I think all three of them are related haha. You should name the columns more semantically.

Answer (score 0):

Both the tables are connected through `people_id` you can use that joining..

```
select * 
from people p 
left join country c on p.id = c.people_id
left join activity a on p.id = a.people_id
```

If you want `people_id's` present in all the three tables then change the `left join` to `inner join`